# driver doesnt find property in device tree during linux init

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, intel-fpga, device-tree

I try to bring up Cortex A9 (Arria V) based board.
During the init the cadence-qspi driver complains that it cannot find the property of the correspondent node int he device tree and fails to initialize. When I look at the representation of the DT, and specifically at /sys/bus/patform/devices/ff705000.qspi/of_node/fifo-depth - I see that it keeps correct value.
What can be the reason for such behavior?
kernel 4.14.130-ltsi from linux-socfpga.git
Thanks,
Ilya

Comment: Please use exact error messages rather than vague descriptions of the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

> During the init the cadence-qspi driver complains that it cannot find the property of the correspondent node int he device tree
>   ...
>   I see that it keeps correct value.

The value of the property is irrelevant when the issue is the driver *"cannot find the property"*.
*"Finding"* a property relates to the name of that property, rather than its value.

> What can be the reason for such behavior?

The likeliest reason is the property name (that you used) in your Device Tree does not match the required property name (specified by a character string) in the kernel driver.

The file **Documentation/devicetree/bindings/mtd/cadence-quadspi.txt** states that the actual name of the property in question is:

```
cdns,fifo-depth
```

whereas you report that your Device Tree uses just `fifo-depth` (and is obviously not a string match).
Beware that there are other required and optional properties for this node that utilize the `cdns,` prefix, so other lines in your Device Tree may need correction.